# Version Control on Visual Basic Internal Web App

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, web-applications, version-control, internals

I work on an internal web app in visual studio that is a visual basic project. This web app is used in a facility and is going to be scaled larger for other facilities. I am looking for the best way to manage 4-5 different versions of this web app. My biggest thought is how to keep them slightly different and if a common update has to go across all apps, I don't have to open each project individually.

- I've thought about creating a new page and using the same backend
- Have the different projects for each place sitting in git but would have to change them all individually for a basic fix
- Have different project folders on the PC but that is very similar to git

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think this is exactly on-topic for SO, but I would strongly recommend against just using project folders, as you won't get any of the history or navigability that you get with real source control. Your best bet may be to do something with different releases in different branches, then you can push common fixes into a base branch and merge them into the other branches.

Comment: Well, without knowing the scope of the difference between the 4-5 different versions you've mentioned bit of a guess.  Project structure wise, you could put all logic and common code in a separate library that the company specific projects reference.

Comment: I would NOT have 5 different copies. DO NOT go down that road. Write all the code and features in the ONE application. If 2 sites have some "minor" difference, then make some settings in a table or whatever, and then code that difference. That way, you simple have ONE copy, ONE application to maintain, and thus better yet you can use GitHub and you off to the races. And if the 5 sites are vast different? Then you have 5 sites, and that's the end of that story.

Answer (score 0):

I would NOT have 5 different copies. DO NOT go down that road.

Write all the code and features in the ONE application.

If 2 sites have some "minor" difference, then make some settings in a table or whatever, and then code that difference.

That way, you simple have ONE copy, ONE application to maintain, and thus better yet you can use GitHub and you off to the races.

And if the 5 sites are vast different? Then you have 5 sites, and that's the end of that story.

In fact, in most cases the fact that you plan to have multiple sites, but each are VERY close, but a bit different? That suggests lack of database normalzing, and plain old simple lack of the developers ability here.

I seen this time and time again! - you will wind up with 5x the work, and 5 times the maintains cost.

I mean, companies build ONE accoutning package, and it can work for a million different kinds of business.

You the developers need to build ONE site. If all those say 5 sites are 99% the same, then it is ONLY lazy designers, and their lack of ability to design the software and code correctly to handle the customers for the given task.

At first, it seems like you're saving money and time. Hey, we just make a WHOLE copy, and then make some changes for one customer. Over time, you will build up what we call in our industry a "technology deficit".

What that means is you're trading your future work for "now", and making a huge compromised design decision.

Over time, you wind up having 5 different sites, only wishing you did not heed the advice here.

If an accounting package can offer flexibility to run darn near any business from a flower shop to a construction company dealing with job costing based on labor or materials, and then next some mom and pop outfit that ONLY sells their time to clean your house?

Then you can also design software the correct way. In near ALL cases, I have found it is lack of correct database normalizing that results in designs that are ONLY a little bit different. This is a VERY bad idea, don't do it.

Right now this might seem easy road, but each passing month, more and more code in those 5 sites will have to be maintained separately, and next thing you know: you have 5 sites to maintain, and 5 code bases. And money spent upgrading one site, improving code, adding new features? You now have to duplicate that by a factor of 5 or however many other sites you have.

Cut and pasting code over and over is bad, when you can often design a set of routines or a good class to achieve the desired outcome.

The same goes for the whole site. All you doing is in effect doing a "huge" cut + paste, but it actually a whole "copy" of the site, and amounts to "worse" then mindless cut + pasting of code. But that is in effect what you are suggesting here.

If those sites are to be "very" similar, or do much the same thing: then build your code, and add some business rules and code that allows such sites to have some different features, or even features enabled etc.

So, right now, it sounds oh so easy to cut + paste some code. Right now it sounds oh so easy to "copy" a project. Don't go down that road unless ALL other reasonable efforts to build one code base and one site are not possible.